# How to split a column in a responsive view using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using **Bootstrap v4 alpha4**

Currently I have:

```
.row
  .col-xs-12.col-md-8
    div A
  .col-xs-12.col-md-4
    div B
    div C
```

For the xs layout, I'd like the div order to be:

```
Div B
Div A
Div C
```

I have no idea how to do this or how to even ask about it. I'm not a front-end dev so I don't know what things are called.

**We can change the HTML to whatever we want.** It does *not* have to stay like it is now.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any class in bootstrap with which we can alter the order of elements.

Comment: @Mr_Green fwiw, the HTML structure that is currently used is not locked. We can do whatever we want to make it possible.

Comment: Have you tried to use flexbox?

Comment: @Olga I have never used flexbox, but I'm open to it if it solves this problem. I'd really appreciate a little extra explanation if you write an answer that uses it.

Comment: Okay, I will make a codepen for you now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap does have [column ordering classes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-column-ordering), but in this case you can simply use the [responsive float classes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#responsive-floats)..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-md-right">
        b
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        c
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/XL5zJELyLD

Comment: *exactly* what I was looking for ^_^

Answer (score 4):

So using the classes from bootstrap and some general style you can achieve that like I did in this pen.

http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/PGadpr

The Html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-right col1"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 pull-left col2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-right col3"></div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.col1{
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.col2{
  background: blue;
  height: 600px;
}
.col3{
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

You can change the default behavior by using their classes for floats(pull-left, pull-right).

Comment: This is slightly over-specified but it also works. Thank you very much. I was not aware of the `pull-*` classes

Answer (score 2):

Instead of flexbox, I used combination of `float` and `position` css properties to get the expected result. Assuming large width as `150px` and small width as `100px`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/zKaJjW?editors=1100)**

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.blue {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
.pink {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  float: right;
}
.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .blue {
    position: relative;
  }
  .green,
  .pink {
    float: none;
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="pink"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. If I was writing vanilla CSS, this is exactly what I'd be looking for.

Comment: @naomik yes. do notice that this works only if you know the parent's width.

Answer (score 2):

As promised, a simple [draft](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAKGgy)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col1">DIV A</div>
   <div class="col2">DIV B</div>
   <div class="col3">DIV C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #86a0ff;
}

.col2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ff6cde;
}

.col3 {
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #35af6d;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .col1 {
    order: 2;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .col2 {
    order: 1;
    width: 200px;
  }

  .col3 {
    order: 3;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

As for explanation, here is a great [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to flexbox. The main idea in my example is that by using order property you can manipulate the order in which blocks are displaying. The main plus of using flexbox is that you won't need to load any library(such as Bootstrap) to achieve the desired result, such as responsiveness. And it also has a good browser [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), unless you need to support older versions of browsers. I hope my answer will be helpful for you!

Comment: thank you. flexbox is so foreign to me. it's nice to see it applied to a problem that i've seen solved other ways.